# How to position elements on an background image in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, media-queries

**->** My goal is to put text on an image background and to move it within the background  as i re-size the browser window (but preventing the text going over the edge of the image). I do not want to keep the text below the image.

**Problem:**
I was following [this](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/build-basic-responsive-site-css-1132756) tutorial for understanding responsive designing. After completing the tutorial I set the goal to move all the text on top of the image. Basically I want to use the red image as a background for everything that is in  `<section>` and  `<aside>` tags (it's just text but I guess it should work also for forms etc.).

My approach was to wrap those two tags in another `<div id="content">` (still under the `<div id="wrapper">`) and then set it to `position:absolute;` in the **CSS**. This wouls overlap the text on the image, however as I re-size the window the text will spill out the background. It is not constrained by the parent div (wrapper?). I thought it would stay within the **wrapper div** as I thought it should be its parent.

Also it floats and it is completely disconnected from the image or the div in which the image is.

**Question:**
So my question is how should I do it instead (keeping it responsive)?

**Code:**
here is on jsfiddle:
[this is the original code](http://jsfiddle.net/YFF9z/) and 
[this is what I tried to do](http://jsfiddle.net/9GTCk/) (try resize the window.. it doesn't look good)

**Example:**
**P.S.** to better understand what I am trying to achieve take a look at [this page](https://www.facebook.com/paper) where you can see the text keeps its position and proportions on a background that you can re-size. (try re-sizing the window of your browser)

Answer (score 0):

In your's jsfiddle css remove `position: fixed;`

```
 #content{
       width: 75%;
       position: fixed;
       /*Remove this line from CSS  (Line number 40 in jsfiddle CSS of your code)*/
       padding: 1%;
       padding-top: 30%;
    }
```

Comment: hi, if I do it that way all the text goes under the image, so it doesnt really use the image as a background.

Comment: I don't want the text to go below the image. It has to use the image as a background for the text. I tried to use position:fixed; and position: absolute; but then when i resize the window it messes up the layout (text going over the edge of the image etc...)

Comment: Why don't you just use the image as a real CSS `background-image`?

Comment: cause it won't show the whole thing. it only display enough background to cover the content. in fact if you create a blank div with background-image for instance it wont show anything till you put some content inside the div.